Scala function consume and return the same upper-bound type
Consider the following:
  sealed trait IntTree
  case class Leaf(value: Int) extends IntTree
  case class Branch(left: IntTree, value: Int, right : IntTree)
  
  def test[A <: IntTree](x: A): A = {
    x match {
      case Leaf(v) => Leaf(v)
      case Branch(l, v, r) => Branch(l, v, r)
    }
  }

In the function test, I have the upper-bound parameter A <: IntTree
I'd like to get it to work like the following:
test(Leaf(1)) // must return Leaf
test(Branch(Leaf(1), 1, Leaf(2))) // must return Branch

val tree: IntTree = Branch(Leaf(1), 1, Leaf(2))
test(tree) // must return IntTree

Though, it does not compile
Like, it's unable to prove that the created Leaf and Branch inside of the pattern matching is actually of type A
Is it possible to express it without the runtime casts?
The best solution I've found so far is:
def test[A <: IntTree](x: A): A = {
  x match {
    case Leaf(v) => Leaf(v).asInstanceOf[A]
    case Branch(l, v, r) => Branch(l, v, r).asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}

Not elegant but working

You can use a typeclass instead. However, note that in this case, it probably doesn't make much sense to preserve the types at all. - BTW, the reason why this doesn't compile is because there is no guarantee that because you matched on Leaf then the type is Leaf, because you are mixing runtime with compile time information. For example, A could have been something like Leaf | Branch it could have been Leaf & MarkType it could have been something like someConstant.type, etc.

It might require you to rethink some aspects of your of code but I think you could work something out with a method on IntTree like def map[B](f: this.type => B): B = f(this). This effectively removes the necessity of a cast as (leaf: Leaf).map(identity) gives you a Leaf...

Which scala version are you using? In 3, I believe you can accomplish this with transparent and inline match
